# Decomposition methods for solving large optimization problems

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-programming

I was wondering if anybody had any suggestions for texts or survey articles on decomposition methods (e.g. primal, dual, Dantzig–Wolfe decompositions) for solving large mathematical programming problems.

I liked Stephen Boyd's ["Notes on Decomposition Methods"](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364b/08-decomposition_notes.pdf), and it would be great to find for example a textbook that covers this topic in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lately I've been working with Decomposition Techniques in Mathematical Programming: Engineering and Science Applications by Conejo, Castillo, Minguez and Garcia-Bertrand (http://www.springer.com/engineering/computational+intelligence+and+complexity/book/978-3-540-27685-2).

It covers several different techniques and when they are applicable, including Dantzig-Wolfe and Benders, and I find it has a good balance of theory and application.  I particularly like the examples, because I think they closely resemble real problems I might wish to formulate and solve.